# How to update position of markers with real time gps coordinates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've got real time gps positions for a few cars and I want to create a map with updating markers. My code works but it doesn't "update" the markers, instead it adds new objects with new coordinates to the leaflet map. After few minutes my map is full of markers. What I'm doing wrong? Here is my basic concept.

```
var intervalV = document.getElementById("intervalValue").value * 1000;
```

document.getElementById("setIntervalButton").onclick = startData;

function startData() {

```
DataInterval = window.setInterval(getNewData, intervalV);
```

};

function getNewData() {
    $.getJSON(server, {
        fun : "GetGpsData",
        userId : "user",
        sessionId : $("#sessionId").val()
    }, fillMap);
}

function fillMap(json) {

`for (var i = 0; i < json.devicesData.length; i++) {
    var positions = json.devicesData[i].positions.length;


        var devicepostiion;

        if (json.devicesData[i].connected == false 
        ) {

            var devicepostion = L.marker([json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lat, json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lon], {
                    icon : offlineCarIcon
                }, {
                    draggable : false
                }).addTo(map);

        } else {


            devicepostion = new L.marker(, {
                    icon : onlineCarIcon
                });


            devicepostion.addTo(map).setLatLng([json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lat, json.devicesData[i].positions[positions - 1].lon]).update();


        }

    }

}`

};

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to update markers with a new visual appearance and location if they already exist on the map...then you should be using [`.setIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon) and [`.setLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setlatlng) on the existing marker instead of making a new one.

Your current code makes new markers in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here your code updated to work as you want. As @snkashis pointed out, you do not need to create a new marker each time

```
var devicePosition = -1;

function fillMap(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.devicesData.length; i++) {
    var data = json.devicesData[i];
      if (data.positions) {
        var index = data.positions.length - 1;

        if (data.positions[index].lat && data.positions[index].lon) {
          var latLng = L.latLng(parseFloat(data.positions[index].lat), parseFloat(data.positions[index].lon));

          if (devicePosition === -1) {
            var devicePosition = L.marker(latLng, {draggable : false})
              .addTo(map);
          } else {
            devicePosition.setLatLng(latLng)
              .update();
          }
          // Optional if you want to center the map on th marker
          // map.panTo(latLng);
        }
    }

    if (data.connected && devicePosition !== -1) {
      devicePosition.setIcon(data.connected ? 'onlineCarIcon' : 'offlineCarIcon');
    }
}
```

If you have multiple markers, you need to update each one accordingly to their id, I suggest to find (or add, if you create the APIs) an unique ID in `json.devicesData[i]`.

Let's suppose the uniqueId of each marker is called, well, uniqueId, then your code can be something like this:

```
var devicePosition = {};

function fillMap(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.devicesData.length; i++) {
    var data = json.devicesData[i];
    var uniqueId = data.uniqueId;
      if (data.positions) {
        var index = data.positions.length - 1;

        if (data.positions[index].lat && data.positions[index].lon) {
          var latLng = L.latLng(parseFloat(data.positions[index].lat), parseFloat(data.positions[index].lon));

          if (!devicePosition[uniqueId]) {
            var devicePosition[uniqueId] = L.marker(latLng, {draggable : false})
              .addTo(map);
          } else {
            devicePosition[uniqueId].setLatLng(latLng)
              .update();
          }
          // Optional if you want to center the map on th marker
          // map.panTo(latLng);
        }
    }

    if (data.connected && devicePosition[uniqueId]) {
      devicePosition[uniqueId].setIcon(data.connected ? 'onlineCarIcon' : 'offlineCarIcon');
    }
}
```